# Subgroups of infinite solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, solvable-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm looking for results of the form "every infinite solvable group contains <...> as a subgroup". Specifically, I believe:

If $G$ is infinite solvable, finitely generated and not virtually cyclic, then $G$ contains as subgroup either the metabelian group $\mathbb Z[1/mn]\rtimes\mathbb Z$, with $\mathbb Z$ acting by multiplication by $m/n$ [possibly $m=n=1$], or the wreath product $\mathbb Z/p\wr\mathbb Z$ for some prime $p$.

(I know that every infinite solvable group contains one of these two subgroups as a section [= quotient of two subgroups], by Kropholler's 1984 result; but really need them as subgroups. In fact, if the answer to the  question is "no", I'm very much interested in a corrected statement with as few extra cases as possible.)

Comment: Are you missing some conditions in 1? Finitely generated? Non-abelian?

Comment: Ouch, yes! I'll edit the question

Comment: Both questions are non-trivial and I don't expect an answer to any of them to solve the other one: I'd suggest to post the second one separately.

Comment: Clarified $m=n=1$ allowed. Hopefully "2." is useful in understanding "1."; one could weaken "2." in requiring $A$ to have infinite index in its normalizer, and then I think it's really an intermediate step towards "1.".

Comment: Anyway I'm close to an answer to 1 and it won't answer 2, so I'd be reluctant to post a long answer complete answer to 1 if it doesn't answer the whole question.

Comment: ... and 2 is a too naive approach to solve 1. A (central-by-metabelian) counterexample is $G/J$, where $G$ is the (f.g.) group of invertible upper triangular matrices with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ and $11,33$ entries equal to $1$. For some injective sequence of primes $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$, $J$ is defined as follows: let $I$ be the subgroup $\bigoplus p_n\mathbf{Z}t^n$ of $\mathbf{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$, and $J$ is the central subgroup consisting of those $e_{13}(x)$ for $x\in I$. Indeed every infinite almost normal abelian subgroup of $G/J$ has unbounded torsion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true: the lamplighter group $L=\mathbb Z/p\wr\mathbb Z$ has a universal central extension (by $H_2(L,\mathbb Z)=(\mathbb Z/p)^\infty$) which does not contain any lamplighter group as a subgroup.

Thanks to @YCor for offsite discussions on this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's universal in the usual sense (I think a group has a universal central extension iff it's perfect). Anyway you might want to include explicitly the extension.